# How can I play CoD 4 Modern Warfare Remastered with friends?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I want to know how I can play CoD 4 MWR on LAN or WiFi/Internet. I have played the non-remastered version by making a LAN on `cmd` but it always ended up lagging with server connections. I looked up Tunngle, but they don't have a server yet. Whenever I make a game on my Internet, no one can find it.

Is there any way of playing on LAN or Internet/WiFi *without* lag or server connections? If there is, how do I do it?

Note: **This is on PC.**

Comment: Is this through Steam?  If so, I assume you have tried inviting your friends through Steam (your questions doesn't make it clear if you tried that or not)?

Comment: No It Is Not Through Steam

Comment: Where did you get it then? Another vendor?

Comment: must be through windows.  they were having huge issues connecting with others.  that would be my guess

Comment: which, in turn, caused Microsoft to refund a ton of money to people that bought it through them.  Might be something to look into so you can purchase it through Steam